# Формирование сводной таблицы и вывод ее на экран

Tags: mysql, sql

Количество полей в таблицах разное. Дубли возможны во второй таблице(первая идет как эталон).

Таблица-1 `mango` поля

- date
- from_number.

Таблица-2 `email` поля

- dateE,
- message.

Вопрос как убрать дубли при выводе (по полям `from_number` и `message`) и в выводе что бы можно было фильтровать/различать(откуда данные с какой таблицы в поле отображаются).

Что я хочу увидеть данные с второй таблицы без дублей (взятые с результирующего запроса) или данные с первой таблицы без дублей (взятые с результирующего запроса) или все вместе без дублей. Если просто взять через `UNION`

```
SELECT start, from_number FROM mango
UNION
SELECT DateE, Message FROM email
```

то появляется общая таблица с 2 двумя первыми полями и невозможно потом в выводе выбрать значения со второй таблицы без дублей. Пробовал через `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT
  start, from_number, DateE, Message 
FROM
  mango 
  LEFT JOIN email ON mango.from_number != email.Message
```

но результат вообще бредовый 7,5 млн записей кода в одной таблице 1500 в другой 4000 записей. Может не правильно как то мыслю формирую и потому идеи никак в голову не прийдут.

Answer (score 0):

что бы определять из какой таблице можно ввести доп поле

```
select distinct x1,x2,x3 
    from
    (
     SELECT start as x1 , from_number as x2, 1 as x3 FROM mango
      UNION
     SELECT DateE, Message, 2 FROM email
    ) as t
```

Comment: пишет: Every derived table must haveits own alias. (На сколько я понял не нравятся псевдонимы sql)

Comment: после последней скобочки добавьте "as t"

Comment: добавил но результата никакого все равно показывает только 2 колонки.

Comment: добавил в запрос 3 столбец

Comment: да так появился секс

Answer (score 0):

@Xramovnic Кроме варианта кроме варианта который вы предложили вывел еще такой: `SELECT mango.start, mango.from_number
FROM mango
LEFT JOIN email ON mango.from_number = email.Message
WHERE (mango.finish-mango.start>59) AND mango.from_number >0 AND email.Message IS NULL AND` Выбираю все звонки больше минуты убираю нулевые телефоны и после джойна убираю те значения которые совпали. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT start
              , from_number 
             -- 'mango' as tablename
FROM mango
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT DateE
              , Message 
             -- 'email'
FROM email
```

**UPD:**

```
SELECT start
     , from_number 
    -- 'mango' as tablename
FROM mango
UNION ALL
SELECT email.DateE
     , email.Message 
    -- 'email'
FROM email
LEFT JOIN mango
  ON  email.DateE = mango.start
  AND email.Message = mango.from_number
WHERE mango.start IS NULL
```

Comment: дистинкт неподходит здесь (насколько помню удаляет дубликаты) т.к. нужно удалить дубликаты во второй таблице по сравнению с первой и только потом ее приджойнить что бы выести скажем так сводные данные. А у вас сначала удаляются дубликаты в самих таблицах а потом все сводится в одну.

Comment: Ну так бы и написал, что тебе нужно всё из первой плюс из второй то, чего нет в первой. Код добавил.